# Tailwind grid class not having effect

Tags: javascript, react-native, tailwind-css, grid-layout

Using React-Native and Tailwind:

Hi, for some reason I just can't get the grid class to work at all no matter how much I tweak it or look for help online.

For example, I have a wrapper component which contains text and children:

```
        <View className="w-3/4">
            <Text className="text-2xl text-center font-bold">{text}</Text>
            <View className="grid grid-cols-3">
                {children}
            </View>
        </View>
```

The children are intended to be an unknown amount of Button components, such that only three are displayed per row. However, it posts them all in a single column (one per row)!

In an attempt to locate and isolate the problem, I've tried other variations of this, e.g attempted to get a working grid using only native components (e.g using only View and Text) with no other modifications, in the App.js but nothing I do seems to affect it in the slightest.

It's almost as if Tailwind doesn't even recognize grid, but there aren't any errors. Other commands such as flex-row work without a hitch

Tried searching the internet for a similar issue but couldn't find one.

For context (in case this is relevant) this is for an Android app